# Adding data to object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting Cannot call method 'push' of undefined. How do you push data to object?

Here's the code.

```
var foo = foo || {};

foo.product.push("bar");
```

Comment: `foo` has no `product` property, so of course it's `undefined`. Please clarify where exactly you want to add the data.

Comment: `foo.product` is `undefined`, not an array, so it has no `push` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` is a method on arrays. (more specifically, `Array.prototype`)

Before you can use an array, you need to create it:

```
foo.products = [];
```

You might not want to overwrite it if it already exists:

```
foo.products = foo.products || [];
```